# How to design data that exploits the workings of TWCS?

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, time-series

My question is, when using TWCS, does Cassandra use its own timestamp (for example, the timestamp of when the row was entered) or can it use the timestamp in the data (for example, the timeuuid or a timestamp field within the row) when using time windows?

For example, if I have a Cassandra database such that:

- I have data with a TTL of 30 seconds
- I have time windows that are 1 second long
- I am writing about 100 1MB rows per second
- I have 3 nodes in my cluster
- I have a partition key consisting of (id, second_of_a_minute)

My understanding is that I should have around 29 SSTables, plus the SSTables in the latest time window, plus any SSTables that have not yet been garbage collected, plus any data that is in the memtable at any time after 30 seconds.

Now, if I query for data that was saved between (now - 20 seconds) and (now - 10 seconds), my data will be stored in roughly 10 SSTables. Does Cassandra check SSTables from every single time window to check whether it stores data within my time frame, or does it only query the SSTables within the time windows that fit in my time query?

Answer (score 0):

No, Cassandra uses the internal write timestamp for TWCS:

> TWCS is designed to work with time series data only. It is based on
>   server time, having nothing at all to do with anything stored in the
>   data itself.

https://blog.pythian.com/proposal-for-a-new-cassandra-cluster-key-compaction-strategy/ (See the section "Limits to Existing Strategies").

The reason the the documentation refers to its use with time series data is that each row written must have a unique primary key - **so that rows are never being re-written**. Usually this key includes a timestamp to make it unique, but it would work just as well with a UUID or some other unique value.